# Define application-wide hot key in mixed wpf/win32 app

Tags: wpf, hotkeys, winapi

I've got a WPF (prism) app, which uses a whole lot of other WPF assemblies and even win32 dlls containing other windows (wpf and win32).

When the user presses a function Key (F2-F12) I want to open spezific program functions.

Something like this:

```
RoutedCommand commandF4 = new RoutedCommand();
commandF4.InputGestures.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.F4));
Application.Current.MainWindow.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(commandF4, CallCommandF4));
```

The problem is: this does only work while the MainWindow has the focus. If I open a secondary WPF window (or a win32 window) the keybinding does not apply anymore.

Is there any way to add an applicationwide global hotkey for F4 (or some other key)?
Or at least a WPF-wide hotkey?

Comment: [Input focus can only be on one window at any point in time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754010.aspx#focus).  You could try catching the keybinding in the secondary window and use [messaging](http://www.google.com/search?q=mvvm+messaging) to communicate to the MainWindow that the key was pressed.  Win32 window may require lower level keyboard hooks and the sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try I think to write a hook to keyboard and attached this hook to listen for keyboard messages from your application's thread.

This is really good example for inspiration: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx.

Just take a note that if you use .Net 4.0 then when you will use SetWindowsHookEx instead of using

```cs
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetModules()[0]
```

as a hMod param, use:

```cs
Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.BaseAddress
```

Comment: Ahh, just noticed that a question is one year old :)